# Query REST API latitude and longitude

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want my users to query two slugs fields (latitude, longitude) and then the 2 slug fields get compared to find nearest distance within 1.5km radius and display the api according to the nearest safehouses. 
For example: when the users add latitude, longitude in their query,

```
         www.example.com/safeplace/?find=-37.8770,145.0442
```

This will show the nearest safeplaces within 1.5km

Here is my function

```
 def distance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):
    R = 6371 # Earth Radius in Km
    dLat = math.radians(lat2 - lat1) # Convert Degrees 2 Radians
    dLong = math.radians(long2 - long1)
    lat1 = math.radians(lat1)
    lat2 = math.radians(lat2)
    a = math.sin(dLat/2) * math.sin(dLat/2) + math.sin(dLong/2) * 
    math.sin(dLong/2) * math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = R * c
    return d
```

Here is my model

```
class Safeplace(models.Model):
    establishment = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    suburb = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    postcode = models.IntegerField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=6,max_digits=10)
    longtitude =  models.DecimalField(decimal_places=6,max_digits=10)
```

Is there a way to run a for loop in my database? I am currently working on Django SQLite. On Views.py, how can i implement the distance function with the user input in my rest api url to find the nearest safeplace and display as REST Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to run a comparison for loop in your views.py. It is pretty difficult to execute but I will try to explain step by step.

assuming you are using that distance(lat, lng, lat2, lng2) function and trying to find the distance within 2km for example.

In views.py

```
import pandas as pd
class someapiview(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SafeplaceSerializer
### Now we are creating definition which sorts parameters lng and lat ###
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Safeplace.Objects.all()
        lat = float(self.query_params.get('lag', None)
        lng = float(self.query_params.get('lng', None)
        ### Now, we are reading your api using pandas ###
        df = pd.read_json('yourapi') ## yourapi is a url to ur api
        obj = []
        for x in range(0, len(df)):
            latx = float(df['latitude'][x])
            lngx = float(df['longitude'][x])
            ### Calculating distance ###
            km = distance(lat, lng, latx, lngx)
            if km <= 2:
                obj.append(df['id'][x])
        ### Django auto generate primary key which usually calls id ###
        ### Now we are going to call those pk as a queryset ###
        return Safeplace.objects.filter(pk__in=obj)
```

I used pandas to work around, the load time might be slow if you have lots of data. However, I think this does the job. Usually Geo Django provides an efficient system to deal with long and lat, however I am not very competent in Geo Django so I cannot really tell. But I Believe this is a good work around.

UPDATE :

you can query with "www.yourapi.com/safeplace?lat=x&lng=y"

I believe you know how to set urls

Comment: yourapi mean `www.yourapi.com/api/safeplace` ?